# error: expected unqualified-id before ‘for’

Tags: c++

The following code returns this: `error: expected unqualified-id before ‘for’`

I can't find what is causing the error. Thanks for the help!

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

const int num_months = 12;

struct month {
    string name;
    int n_days;
};

month *months = new month [num_months];

string m[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
              "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
int n[] = {31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

for (int i=0; i<num_months; i++) {
    // will initialize the months
}

int main() {
    // will print name[i]: days[i]
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but still very important, is that you are using "new", but you are never calling "delete", which leaks memory.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your `for` loop is outside a function body.

Answer (score 10):

Ok just to make this answer clear (since I made the rookie mistake too).

***the for loop was outside `int main()` (or any other function) along with everything else since main() sits by itself empty at the bottom of the code.***

Sorry more than needed to be said for some but since this issue is more directed to newbies a more elaborate explanation is needed.

Comment: Everything else *can* sit outside of main() if desired, and alot of the rest (like structs and classes) *has to* sit outside of main(). Plus, this implies that 'main()' is the only function that can contain variables. The problem is that the for() loop is outside of *any* function, not main() only.

Comment: @JaminGrey & Anthony Flores, you answers helped. My for loop was out of a function and I didn't have a main().

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly related but might be helpful to someone finding this.
I got a similar error `error: expected unqualified-id before 'continue'`

My problem was that I wrote std::continue like this:

```
std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for(int i: a)
{
    if(i == 3)std::continue;
}
```

instead of just continue:

```
std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for(int i: a)
{
    if(i == 3)continue;
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is mostly about answering the question. You shouldn't submit an answer that discusses a different issue.

Comment: @user904963 this is the first match when you google the error. So I thought posting it here would be helpful to anyone else who stumbles upon this question with same issue as mine.  I can delete my answer if you think it's inappropriate.

Comment: I'm not an expert on which questions should be deleted. Unfortunately, that compiler error matches up to many possible causes. I'm getting the vague understanding that it happens when a C++ program is malformed such as `std::` before `continue` or, in this case, a `for` statement outside of a function.  Searching for the error, I saw it happen when a person put a `;` like `main() ; {...`. Another user had `return 0;` outside his main function. Yet another person wrote `main() { /*code*/};`. It's tricky for new programmers to diagnose based on the message.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31141853)